# Coseparating family in the category of groupoids

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

Does the category of (small) groupoids admit a small coseparating/cogenerating set of objects? I suppose $\mathbf{Cat}$ doesn't, but so far I have no clue about $\mathbf{Grpd}$.